# Disabling mouse Input to a GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is there a way in Unity to disable mouse inputs to a GameObject without removing/disabling the collision box?

I want to write a script that would ignore the mouse input of the object after it was pressed once. It's not hard to do so within the scope of the script, but I want other scripts on that objects to ignore mouse input without modifying all the other scripts.

Comment: Could you clarify a bit? I can't make out what you want.

Comment: I want to make a script that after a single input (e.g. OnMouseDown()) ignores all following inputs. Not only in the scope of that script, but other scripts that are attached to that GameObject. And all that without removing/disabling the objects collision box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [OnMouseDown documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html)

> This function is not called on objects that belong to Ignore Raycast layer.

So, one way of doing this is switching the layer of the object to Ignore Raycast.

```
this.gameObject.layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Ignore Raycast");
```

But if you have other functionality that depends on raycasting, those will be disabled too (unless they are raycasting in other layers).

Comment: This is new info for me. I always thought you'd still need to filter the layer in the raycast.

Comment: I don't think Raycasting always requires a layer. I think it has a default layer that you can override. Also, the OnMouseDown is triggered by a Raycast that Unity is performing, so I don't think you can change its layer. I may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

That could be achieved by placing a script which validates/filters the inputs. It could be a single bool `reveiceInput` in an another script which is read every time you get input. So if that `receiveInput` is false after the first mouseDown the others won't affect it.

Comment: I don't understand how this will work without editing existing scripts that are on that object.

Comment: @CreativeMagic Of course you have to edit the scripts, but you mentioned, you just did not want to remove the collider.

Comment: read the last sentence of my question, you'll see that I exactly said that I don't want to edit all the other scripts. And notice that the question was not edited either ;)